# Why the tcsetpgrp() call does not work as expected?

Tags: c, unix, terminal, signals, background-foreground

Looking for a snippet of code showing the use of a `tcsetpgrp()` call, I came across https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxbd00/rttcsp.htm, where the code of CELEBT10.c is shown.

When executing the code I get

```
original foreground process group id of stdout was 59741
now setting to 59742
```

then the program stops.

With `ps -aj` I see the group change (`setpgid()`) works correctly.
In fact, when I send the child a `SIGCONT` signal, the child executes the remaining part and exit (together with the waiting parent).

Adding a `sleep()` after `tcsetpgrp()`, `ps -aj` also shows the parent’s group is still the foreground one. That is, the `tcsetpgrp()` call fails.

Can somebody explain why the child stops in the `tcsetpgrp()` call and why it fails?

Answer (score 2):

This is because of `SIGTTOU` generated by attempting `tcsetpgrp` *from a background process*, as noted in the manual:

> If tcsetpgrp() is called from a background process group against the caller's controlling terminal, a SIGTTOU signal may be generated depending how the process is handling SIGTTOUs:

You can see this by running `strace -f ./a.out` and observing the output of the child process (`-f` means follow forks):

```
[pid  4062] setpgid(4062, 0)            = 0
[pid  4062] write(1, "now setting to 4062\n", 20now setting to 4062
) = 20
[pid  4062] ioctl(1, TIOCSPGRP, [4062]) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
[pid  4062] --- SIGTTOU {si_signo=SIGTTOU, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
```

The `tcsetpgrp()` is translated by the library to an `ioctl`, and we can see what's up.

Copying the pointed-to code here:

```
/* CELEBT10
 *
 *    This example changes the PGID.
 *
 *     */
#define _POSIX_SOURCE
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>


int main() {
  pid_t pid;
  int status;

  if (fork() == 0)
  {
    // signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_IGN);  // UNCOMMENT ME
    if ((pid = tcgetpgrp(STDOUT_FILENO)) < 0)
      perror("tcgetpgrp() error");
    else {
      printf("original foreground process group id of stdout was %d\n",
             (int) pid);
      if (setpgid(getpid(), 0) != 0)
        perror("setpgid() error");
      else {
        printf("now setting to %d\n", (int) getpid());
        if (tcsetpgrp(STDOUT_FILENO, getpid()) != 0)
          perror("tcsetpgrp() error");
        else if ((pid = tcgetpgrp(STDOUT_FILENO)) < 0)
          perror("tcgetpgrp() error");
        else
          printf("new foreground process group id of stdout was %d\n", (int) pid);
        fflush(stdout);
      }
    }
  }
  else wait(&status);
}
```

See the note "UNCOMMENT ME" and it will allow the function to continue:

```
$ ./a.out
original foreground process group id of stdout was 4070
now setting to 4071
new foreground process group id of stdout was 4071
```

It's been ages since I had to do this so I'm fuzzy on the rationale, but I believe the idea is that background process ought not write to the terminal and mess up whatever the foreground process is doing.  Many times code that puts itself in the background redirects its input/output to detach itself from the foreground terminal.

By catching (or ignoring) the signal, the code is making its intentions explicit, but I'm not sure a casual "just ignore the signal" is automatically the right answer; we'd need to understand how this code fit into the bigger picture.